# Plotting distribution intervals of a ecdf

Tags: r, distribution, intervals, ecdf

this is the first example of the ecdf() function in R:

```
F10 <- ecdf(rnorm(10)
plot(F10)
plot(F10, verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE)
```

[image: plot]

Now I would like to "zoom" in the y-axis so that it only shows the interval of 0.9-1.0.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Interval (0.90, 1.00) on the X or Y ? Do you mean to use `xlim` or `ylim` ?

Comment: Interval on the Y. Does it work with ylim? If yes, how?

Comment: `plot(F10, ylim=c(0.90, 1.00))` Same for `xlim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `rbm` this is the easy solution:

`plot(F10, ylim=c(0.90, 1.00))`